# Computing Matrix Representation of a Linear Transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, integration, matrices, derivatives, linear-transformations

I'm having some trouble figuring out this question:

Let $V=P_3(\mathbb{R})$ and $W=P_4(\mathbb{R})$.

Let $D:W\to V$ be the derivative mapping $D(p)=p'$.

Let $Int:V\to W$ be the integration mapping $Int(p)=\int_0^x p(t)dt$.

Let $\alpha=\{1,x,x^2,x^3\}$ and $\beta=\{1,x,x^2,x^3,x^4\}$ be the standard bases in $V$ and $W$.

Compute : $[D]_{\alpha\beta}$ ,  $[Int]_{\beta\alpha}$ , $[DInt]_{\alpha\alpha}$ , $[IntD]_{\beta\beta}$.

I'm not sure how to go about finding the matrices that represent these transformations. Any help at all would be appreciated.

My reasoning is that $[D]_{\alpha\beta}$ would equal:

\begin{Bmatrix} 
      1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
      0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
      0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
      0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0
   \end{Bmatrix}

Since if you multiply that matrix by

$\beta=\{1,x,x^2,x^3,x^4\}$

You would end up with

$\alpha=\{1,x,x^2,x^3\}$

Comment: Do you know how to construct the matrix of a linear transformation with respect to specific given bases? In your class they should've told you that -- there's basically a step-by-step procedure for it.

Comment: Could you remind me of that process, I've tried it myself but I don't think I'm doing it correctly

Comment: You apply the transformation to each element of the given basis of the domain space, and each time record the coordinates of the result with respect to the given basis in the target space -- that's how you get the columns of the matrix that you need to construct. If you show us some of your work, of what you've tried, then we can check whether it's correct, and if it isn't -- what went wrong in it.

Comment: Then can you show us what you've got, at least for one of them?

Comment: I've edited it to show what I got so far

Comment: Multiplying a matrix by a set does not make any sense. You have to understand that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are sets of elements, **NOT** vectors. And then why would this matrix represent $D$, not some other transformation? You didn't even use $D$ in "constructing" it.

Comment: Could you point me in the right direction, because I don't really understand what it is I'm supposed to be doing

Comment: The derivative of $x^2$ is not $x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's apply the transformation $D$ to each element of the given basis $\beta=\{1,x,x^2,x^3,x^4\}$ of $W=P_4(\mathbb{R})$ in the order they are listed, and write each result with respect to the given basis $\alpha=\{1,x,x^2,x^3\}$ of $V=P_3(\mathbb{R})$.

$D(1)=(1)'=0=0\cdot1+0\cdot x+0\cdot x^2+0\cdot x^3$, therefore the first column is $\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$.

$D(x)=(x)'=1=1\cdot1+0\cdot x+0\cdot x^2+0\cdot x^3$, therefore the second column is $\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$.

$D(x^2)=(x^2)'=2x=0\cdot1+2\cdot x+0\cdot x^2+0\cdot x^3$, therefore the third column is $\begin{bmatrix}0\\2\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$.

$D(x^3)=(x^3)'=3x^2=0\cdot1+0\cdot x+3\cdot x^2+0\cdot x^3$, therefore the fourth column is $\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\3\\0\end{bmatrix}$.

$D(x^4)=(x^4)'=4x^3=0\cdot1+0\cdot x+0\cdot x^2+4\cdot x^3$, therefore the fifth column is $\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\\4\end{bmatrix}$.

Thus the desired matrix is $[D]_{\alpha\beta}=\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0&0&0\\0&0&2&0&0\\0&0&0&3&0\\0&0&0&0&4\end{bmatrix}$.